# Idele class group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have problem showing $I_K/K^\times \cong I_K^1/K^\times \oplus\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ as topological groups where $K$ is a number field. Is there any help?

I know they are isomorphic as groups. So I also wonder which condition will make a split group exact sequence into a split topological group exact sequence if the groups are topological groups.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is described in any standard algebraic number theory textbook, e.g. Lang.

Comment: @D_S, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point is to embed $\mathbb R_{>0}$ as a closed multiplicative subgroup at the infinite places.  Consider the product $K_{v_1} \times \cdots \times K_{v_s}$ of the completions of $K$ at the infinite places.  For each positive real number $\rho$, let $\underline{\rho}= (\rho^{1/n}, ... , \rho^{1/n})$, where $n = [K : \mathbb Q]$.  We can think of $\underline{\rho}$ as an idele, which has value $1$ at each finite place, and which has idele norm $\|\underline{\rho}\| = \rho$.

For $xK^{\ast} \in I_K/K^{\ast}$, the maps $xK^{\ast} \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|} K^{\ast}$ and $xK^{\ast} \mapsto \|x\|$ into $I_K^{1}/K^{\ast}$ and $\mathbb R_{>0}$ respectively, are continuous.  Therefore, from the definition of the product topology, we get a continuous map

$$I_K/K^{\ast} \rightarrow I_K^1/K^{\ast} \times \mathbb R_{>0}.$$

The inverse map, $(xK^{\ast}, \rho) \mapsto \underline{\rho}x K^{\ast}$, is also continuous.  This shows we have a homeomorphism.